# overlapping ifs refactoring of java

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

### I'm using java8.
I made the code below from the sample.
I want to refactoring this, but I don't know how.
Let me know if you have any good ideas.

Add Description :
There was some error in coding, so I corrected it.

---

```
String returnStr = "";
if(a != "" && b != "" && c != ""){
    returnStr = "1";
}else{
    if(a != "" && b != ""){
        returnStr = "2";
    }else if(a != "" && c != ""){
        returnStr = "3";
    }else if(b != "" && c != ""){
        returnStr = "4";
    }else{
        if(a != ""){
            returnStr = "5";
        }else if(b != ""){
            returnStr = "6";
        }else if(c != ""){
            returnStr = "7";
        }else{
            returnStr = "8";
        }
    }
}

return returnStr;
```

Comment: [Do not compare `String`s with `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: What is `int return = "";` supposed to mean?

Comment: Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Code review is off-topic, but you might want to check out our sister site [codereview.se]. Please make sure to read _its_ on-topic page, take its tour, and read its How to Ask page before posting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all those `else` and you could make it more concise and clear like this:

```
if(a != "" && b != "" && c != "") return 1;
if(a != "" && b != "") return 2;
if(a != "" && c != "") return 3;
if(b != "" && c != "") return 4;
if(a != "") return 5;
if(b != "") return 6;
if(c != "") return 7;
return 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct an `int` from the 3 bits effectively implied by the "emptiness" checks:

```
int i = (a != "" ? 4 : 0) | (b != "" ? 2 : 0) | (c != "" ? 1 : 0);
```

(Yes, you should be using `equals`, or `isEmpty()`, instead of `!=`. That's not really the point).

This gives a number in the range 0 to 7, inclusive.

Construct an 8-element list or array, where the number is the value you want to return.

Then, use `i` from above to select an element from that list/array:

```
return list.get(i);  // or array[i]
```

Comment: Or, since in the original code is always returning a value in the range 1 to 8 inclusive that is equal to the value that i would have in your version + 1, simply return i + 1, I guess?

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper No, it's not equal.  You could `return (i == 3 || i == 4) ? i + 1 : 8 - i;` but an array is less confusing.

Comment: Ah, true, it's not the same order. My bad.